# Symfony 3 mock service in functional tests phpunit and liip

Tags: symfony, phpunit, liipfunctionaltestbundle

I use Symfony 3.4. I have functional tests which extend from `Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase` and in some function I want mock some service, I create mockobject for service but in action I still have original service, how to mock service

in my function

```
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(AdditionalFunction::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $this->getContainer()->set('app.additional_function', $mock);


    $this->getClient()->request(
        Request::METHOD_GET,
        $uri
    );
```

and in my action `$uri`

```
public function sendAction(OutboundInvoice $outboundInvoice)
{
    $test = $this->get('app.additional_function');
```

in variable `$test` I had original class `‌AppBundle\Helper\AdditionalFunction`

How to mock service ?

Comment: Did you try with `$this->getClient()->getContainer()->set('app.additional_function', $mock);`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following, as suggested in https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/issues/107#issuecomment-358267059

```
$mock = $this->createMockInAnyWayYouWant();
static::$kernel->getContainer()->set('id_service', $mock);
```